# Calling random functions from a list when functions have different number of parameters

Tags: python, list, function, random, arguments

I'm a beginner trying to write a text based game, something like Monopoly. Since I learned about functions I thought the best way would be to define a function for each square. Then, I would put the functions in a list and randomly call them. The problem is the functions might require different number of arguments or no argument.

```
from random import randrange

def foo1(param_of_foo1):
    x = param_of_foo1 + 1
    print "x is:", x

def foo2(param_of_foo2):
    y = param_of_foo2 + 2
    print "y is:", y

def foo3(useless_param):
    print "I have a parameter but I don't really need it..."

list_of_foo = [foo1, foo2, foo3]

arg = 0

function_index = randrange(0,3)

print "Function index is:", function_index

if function_index == 0:
    arg = 4

elif function_index == 1:
    arg = 10

list_of_foo [function_index](arg)
```

As you can see this seems to work but it is not an elegant solution. I don't like that I had to define the third function with a parameter even if it doesn't need it, of course. And I also don't like that I have to specify a condition for some functions to let them know what they should use as arguments.
Surely there must be a better way to do this. There always is. Thank you and sorry if this is stupid or it has already been asked. I couldn't find an answer.

Updated code:

```
from random import randrange
from functools import partial

def foo1(arg_of_foo1):
    x = arg_of_foo1 + 1
    print "x is:", x

def foo2(arg1_of_foo2,arg2_of_foo2):
    y = arg1_of_foo2 + arg2_of_foo2
    print "y is:", y

def foo3():
    print "I don't need a parameter so I don't have one."

a = 0
b = 0

while b <= 100:
    print'='*20
    random_number = randrange(0,3)

    a += 1
    b += 10

    print "a is:", a
    print "b is:", b
    print "r_n is:", random_number

    print '-'*10
    raw_input("[Enter] to execute random function")

    list_of_foo = [partial(foo1,a), partial(foo2,a,b), partial(foo3)]

    list_of_foo[random_number]()
```

This code gets rid of the conditional statements and of the unnecessary parameters. 
Thank you, inspector!

Comment: Just throwing a few ideas out there, since I think this is the kind of question that doesn't have a definitive answer.  1) It doesn't look like there is any actual input that changes the value of the argument.  Perhaps it makes more sense to just get rid of the argument and have a constant inside the function?  2) You might look at using classes as an alternative form of abstraction, which may or may not be more appropriate for this particular scenario.  Again, it's hard to give a definitive answer without knowing all the details, but maybe that's a start.

Comment: A rather ambitious project to begin with.  You may consider checking out [Game Elements as Programmatic Objects](http://pythonmonopoly.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/game-elements-as-programmatic-objects/) for an overview of an entirely different method of game development using objects as opposed to defining discrete functions for each square.

Comment: Thank you Justin and JonB. I will think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things that you can do:

1. Use `*args` in the function definition
2. Rewrite your functions to take a list (or tuple, or dict) as the only parameter, and read the actual parameters out of it
3. Use `ast` to read the function signature, and give it the correct number of parameters (left out for now)

---

#### Using `*args`

In python, you can define `*args` to be the list of arguments your function gets, which will assign the sequence of arguments to a list called `args`:

```
In [113]: def func(*args):
   .....:     print "the arguments are:", ' '.join(args)
   .....:     

In [114]: func()
the arguments are:

In [115]: func('a')
the arguments are: a

In [116]: func('a', 'b')
the arguments are: a b
```

So, with that in mind, you can do:

```
def foo1(*args):
    param_of_foo1 = args[0]  # any other arguments will be discraded
    x = param_of_foo1 + 1
    print "x is:", x

def foo3(*uselessArgs):
    print "I have a parameter but I don't really need it..."
```

You can still call `foo3()` and `foo3(1,2,3)`

---

#### Using lists

This is the same idea as before, but  you call with a list of arguments:

```
def foo1(L):
    param_of_foo1 = L[0]  # other entries will be ignored
```

This will need to be called with a list of params: `foo1([1])` or `foo1([1,2,3])`

```
def foo1(arg):
    print "I got this as my argument:", arg
```

Now, `foo1([1,2,3])` will give:

> I got this as my argument: [1,2,3]

Since `arg` behaves like any other list (just like in the `*args` case), you shoul dbe able to pull out any number of arguments (as long as they are supplied). So since the maximum number of arguments your functions require is 1, always supply a list of at least one argument, and any extras will be ignored (especially by `foo3`)

There is another way, using `ast`, but I don't think that's what you're after, so I'll leave it out for now (comment, and I'll add it in)

---

If, on the other hand, you are only ever going to call `foo1` with 4 and `foo2` with 10, then this should work for you:

```
>>> import functools
>>> import random
>>> def foo1(param_of_foo1):
...     x = param_of_foo1 + 1
...     print "x is:", x
... 
>>> def foo2(param_of_foo2):
...     y = param_of_foo2 + 2
...     print "y is:", y
... 
>>> def foo3(useless_param):
...     print "I have a parameter but I don't really need it..."
... 
>>> f = functools.partial(foo1, 4)
>>> f()
x is: 5
>>> list_of_foo = [functools.partial(foo1, 4), functools.partial(foo2, 10), functools.partial(foo3, 'discarded argument')]
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
y is: 12
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
y is: 12
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
y is: 12
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
I have a parameter but I don't really need it...
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>> random.choice(list_of_foo)()
x is: 5
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, inspector. As I see it, *args helps when one needs to send different arguments to the same function. However, in my case we talk about a random function which needs the same argument(s) every time it is called. Like I wrote in the example, if random function is 'foo1', then send 'arg = 4'. The problem with list_of_foo[function_index](arg) is that I don't know what 'function_index' will be, so of course I don't know what arguments to pass. This might be simpler than everyone thinks. I just need a kind of list from where I can call a function AND its argument.

Comment: @NyckM.: do you never want to call `foo1` with anything other than 4 and `foo2` with anything other than 10?

Comment: In the game they are actually variables so... they vary. If they didn't this would be easy even for me... I guess.

Comment: So I noticed that I can use variables instead of integers in your functool example which is exactly what I want. Hopefully I will find a way to use randrange with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just do `fn(*args)` for unknown number of parameters, or unknown types of parameters.

Comment: This is indeed the right answer, but probably needs more explanation since OP is a newcomer to Python.

Comment: In my case we talk about calling random functions which require specific arguments. *args might work somehow but I don't see how. I dare to say I don't think it can work in this case.

Comment: @NyckM. Do you have to have three separate functions, foo1, foo2, foo3, or can you combine them into one function that accepts an unknown parameter?

Comment: To make it more simple to understand, what I basically want is a list where I can put the function name together with the name(s) of the argument(s) to be passed. Something like: list_of_foo = [foo1(arg1,arg2), foo2(), foo3(arg1)]. The use of parentheses will trigger the function so this does not work. A dictionary might be useful somehow. Also tuples might help. If I could unpack a tuple of two or more elements, where the first element is the name of the function and the other elements are the arguments it would be cool.